# AnyLogic: Is it possible to change the tank's capacity in running time?

Tags: anylogic

I tried to change the tank's capacity in running time, as the capacity may be affected by the pressure. But the function setCapacity() is not working, I received the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: root.storages[4].tank:
capacity cannot be changed dynamically
```

is there any other method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

No. Some things cannot be changed at runtime, this is one of them. If your capacity is changed by pressure, the fluid library and a `tank` object are not the correct match.

You are basically talking about a flexible "balloon", which you'd need to model yourself. Not impossible but well beyond using a simple pre-designed object :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. May I ask if there is any suggestion for this self-created tank? and is it possible to connect it with the fluid library's block, because I have built the structure using fluid library's blocks.

Comment: Many ideas and no, not easily possible to link it. But also not impossible. But none of this is easy, tbh. Might be better to simplify and work around the issue